# Запятая после видимо: Видимо (,)нет

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после слова "видимо"
-Ты понимаешь значение слова "абстрактный"?
-Да.
-Видимо (,)нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая после *видимо* нужна, поскольку здесь оно выступает в роли вводного слова.

http://elhow.ru/ucheba/russkij-jazyk/punktuacija/kak-vydeljaetsja-zapjatymi-vidimo